# Get raised error in a class to main()

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, user-defined, raise

Hi im currently doing a program like this.

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, text = "Correct")
        self.text = text
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.kod)

class Atom(self):
.
.
.
    try:
        function()
    else:
        raise MyError("Incorrect use of function")


def main():
    try:
        a = Atom()
    except:
        # Here i want to print the error that was raised
```

What I think I understand is that the error is raised in an object created in Atom().
But I want to send it to my main program and do the print of the error MyError there.
Is it possible to do this and how should I write it so that the correct text of exception is printed since i will have several different error messages.

If i come to the except statement I would want to get the message "Incorrect use of function" printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're pretty close:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, text = "Correct")
        self.text = text
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.kod)

class Atom(self):
.
.
.
    try:
        function()
    except:  # try: ... else: raise ... seems a bit funky to me.
        raise MyError("Incorrect use of function")


def main():
    try:
        a = Atom()
    except Exception as err:  # Possibly `except MyError as err` to be more specific
        print err
```

The trick is that when you catch the error, you want to bind the exception instance to a name using the `as` clause.  Then you can print it, look at it's attributes, re-raise or pretty much do anything you choose with it.

---

Please note that this code still isn't "clean".  Generally, you want to limit exception handling as much as possible -- only catch exceptions that expect to see and that you know how to handle.  Otherwise, you can sometimes mask hard to find bugs in your code.  Because of this:

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    ...
```

is discouraged (it catches all sorts of things like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`) ...  Instead:

```
try:
    do_something()
except ExceptionIKnowHowToHandle:
    ...
```

is advised.

Comment: Yes, you'll always get the last error -- Of course, you can always add the original error as an attribute of the final error and tack it on in your exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *never* do a blank `except`. That will catch *all* errors, including things like `KeyboardInterrupt` - so you won't be able to ctrl-c out of your program. Here you should just catch `MyError`.

The except clause also allows you to assign the actual exception to a variable, which you can then print or do anything else with. So you can do:

```
try:
    ...
except MyError as e:
    print e.text
```